# Plot graph without using formula to label the arrows in package digest

Tags: r, diagram

I am trying to plot a graph as follow:

```
library(diagram)
Numgenerations <- 6
DiffMat <- matrix(data = 0, nrow = Numgenerations, ncol = Numgenerations)
AA <- DiffMat
AA[1,4] <- "f[3"
name <- c(expression(Age[0]), expression(Age[1]), expression(Age[2]),
expression(Age[3]), expression(Age[4]), expression(Age[5]))
plotmat(A = AA, pos = 6, curve = 0.7, name = name, lwd = 2,
  arr.len = 0.6, arr.width = 0.25, my = -0.2,
  box.size = 0.05, arr.type = "triangle", dtext = 0.95,
  main = "Age-structured population model 1")
```

Then, the R treats "f[3" as formula and returns

```
Error in parse(text = txt) : <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: f[3
  ^
```

I look into the [vignettes with the package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/diagram/vignettes/diagram.pdf). In section 2.3, it writes:

> The next example uses formulae to label the arrows 1 . This is done by passing a data.frame rather than a matrix to function `plotmat`

However, what I pass to `plotmat` in the previous example is a matrix instead of data.frame. Now I find no way to avoid the `parse` in `plotmat` before plotting the labels.

The version of the diagram package is 1.6.

Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: I think your only problem here is that "f[3" should be "f[3]"... Let me know if that doesn't fix it

Comment: I do need to print "f[3" as label. In my case, it has a special meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put f[3 in double quotes like this:

```
library(diagram)
Numgenerations <- 6
DiffMat <- matrix(data = 0, nrow = Numgenerations, ncol = Numgenerations)
AA <- as.matrix(DiffMat)
AA[1,4] <- "'f[3'" #double then single quotes
name <- c(expression(Age[0]), expression(Age[1]), expression(Age[2]),
          expression(Age[3]), expression(Age[4]), expression(Age[5]))

plotmat(A = AA, pos = 6, curve = 0.7, name = name, lwd = 2,
        arr.len = 0.6, arr.width = 0.25, my = -0.2,
        box.size = 0.05, arr.type = "triangle", dtext = 0.95,
        main = "Age-structured population model 1")
```

[image]